# Easy online filehosting

Tags: pdf, website

I've had a request from a client for a basic restaurant website, 1 page, which is linked to 2 pdf menus.

They want to be able to update the PDF's but I already know now that they won't be able to handle using FTP for this.

Since it is such a simple website I don't really want to have to invest in setting up a full on CMS for them just to handle uploading a couple of PDF's.

Are there any services who could host the file in such a way that it is ridiculously easy for them to upload the file and have it preserve the original link from the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dropbox](http://dropbox.com), though it no longer includes the Public folder by default in a new account, [still allows you to enable it](https://www.dropbox.com/login?cont=https://www.dropbox.com/enable_public_folder). Links to files in your Public folder are fixed, even when the files are updated, as long as the file names are not modified.

It's easy, and I can't imagine your restaurant owner will have PDF menus that exceed the allotted space of a free account.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise the links were fixed. I'll look into this cheers

Answer (score 1):

amazon s3 maybe ? hosting the website out of the s3 bucket

Comment: Amazon S3 isn't exactly simple to manage if a person cannot log into a stored ftp website and upload a file.

Comment: last time i left something like that as a comment, i got told it should have been an answer. @ramhound, s3 isn't hard. Login with a gui, upload the file with a single click; done. I realise it's a big scary service, but their requirements need none of those bits.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at the dropbox route, if that fails I think this will be a good option. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox can host static files no issue, and the link is based on the filename. It even does versioning, and there's a few services that let you use a [properish](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox) domain name or even a [mini cms](http://droppages.com/). You can then use the dropbox client on a supported system or the website to update. Easy as can be.